# Множественное число слов враг, порог, друг, бог

Tags: этимология, множественное-число

Почему в русском языке формой множественного числа слова *друг* является *друзья*, а не *други*?

По аналогии с другими группами слов:

*враг враги;
порог пороги;
бог боги.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. У слова **друг** богатая история и в разные времена / в разных местах формы для множественного числа и/или собирательные были разными. В гугло-книгах можно найти "Лекции по истории русского языка" Е.Будде (примерно столетней давности), в которой говорится, что форма **други** — более поздняя (она не раз встречается в произведениях А.С.Пушкина, например), а ранее мн.ч. было **друзи**. Были известны формы *дружие, дружья*. Неясно, возникла ли форма *друзья* от собирательного *дружие* через *дружье* или образовалось как множественное число непосредственно от *друзи*.

Я думаю, что в какой-то момент некоторые из этих слов семантически разошлись. Так *дружья* означало супругов (ср. *подружжя* — супруги в укр. языке), *дружие* – собирательную форму и т.п. И этот процесс подтолкнул носителей языка к "решению" отделить форму множественного числа — **друзья**.

**Добавление.**
Стоит обратить внимание, что древняя форма множественного числа сохранилась в украинском языке: **друзi**.

Answer (score 1):

Тот же вопрос можно задать **по целому ряду существительных м.р.**

**Основным окончанием** в форме мн. числа является окончание ***Ы/И***, но ряд существительных имеют **вариантное окончание *А/Я,*** например: брат, зять, клин, брус, князь, стул, муж (супруг), прут и т.д.

Для некоторых существительных возможны **оба варианта**: грозди и гроздья, суки и сучья, листы (бумаги) и листья (на дереве).

Форма "други" является устаревшей. Почему? Также можно спросить: почему ***столы, но стулья.*** Разные могут быть причины: фонетические, семантические.

Например, можно предположить **фонетическое сходство** прилагательного ***другой*** и падежных форм существительного ***друг*** во мн. числе.

Answer (score 1):

Современная форма мн.ч. друзья - бывшая собирательная форма с суфф.-j-, с изменением перед ним г > з (Ср. др.-
 рус.собир. дружья "друзья", где г > ж . Старая форма друзи сохранилась в укр.друзi- "друзья")

Чтобы понять, откуда взялось такое чередование, нужно вспомнить закон слогового сингармонизма и две палатализации согласных. Вот материал одного из учебников по исторической грамматике:

> В результате второй палатализации у существительных наблюдалось
>   чередование заднеязычных со свистящими в положении перед гласными [i]
>   и [ě], возникшими из дифтонгов *[oi], *[ai]: [k] > [c’], [g] > [z’]
>   (через ступень [d’z’]), [ch] > [s’] на границе основы и окончания
>   г//з’, к// ц, х//с’. Свистящие выступали в формах Им.п. ед.ч. вълкъ –
>   Им.п. мн.ч. вълци, Им.п. ед.ч. нога – М.п. ед.ч. на нозЬ, однокоренное
>   к слову слухъ – послоуси). Это чередование было вызвано 2
>   палатализацией, и было утрачено в 14 веке после непереходного
>   смягчения заднеязычных г,к,х. Становятся возможными сочетания ги, ки,
>   хи и гѣ, кѣ, хѣ на границе основы и окончания. Поэтому произошло
>   выравнивание парадигмы- унификация падежных форм существительных по
>   единому образцу, т. е. произошло устранение чередований заднеязычных
>   со свистящими образованными в результате 2 палатализации. Н-р: до 14
>   века было руцѣ – в 14 веке рукѣ по аналогии с остальными падежными
>   формами этого же слова.
>          Унификация (или выравнивание парадигмы) происходит в следующих формах:
>   1. У имен сущ-ых скл. на *а (долгий) в дат., мест. пад., ед.ч.: нозѣ- ногѣ
>   2. У имен сущ-ых скл. на * о (краткий) в мест. п. ед. ч.: о волцѣ-о волкѣ; в мест. п. мн. ч.: о волцѣхѣ- о волкѣхѣ; в им. п. мн. ч.:
>   волци-волки. Единственное слово, где на границе основы и окончания
>   сохраняется результат 2 палатализации - это слово друзья.

http://linguistics-konspect.org/?content=12241